# How to yield and proceed to parse method without scrapy.Request in Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a list of URLs.
The targeted website doesn't render data without javascript. So the script is fully dependent on Selenium. To maintain the project structure I've to implement it in a scrapy project.

Currently, I'm sending **scrapy.Request** to the URL. Then in the **parse method** getting back the URL from **response.request.url**

I'm trying to find a way to eliminate the use of **scrapy.Request** and proceed to **parse method** and **yield the data** for every URL from **all_urls** list

Here is my code -

```
class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "sample_spider"
    all_urls = ["url1","url2"]
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url) #Looking to eliminate this "scrapy.Request"

    def parse(self, response):
        bot = self.driver
        bot.get(response.request.url)

        sample_data = bot.get_element_by_xpath("//h1")
        yield {"data":sample_data}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer in the meantime?

Comment: I have a similar problem. While I am interested in a real answer, my workaround is to call a random & lightweight http page (https://api.ipify.org/ for instance)